# How to matched a pattern of only static files with all modified changes to run zappa command in github action?

Tags: github-actions

In yaml file, how to run zappa command `manage dev collectstatic --noinput` and `if condition` for matching only static files pattern?###

```yaml
name: CI/CD

on: push

jobs:
 deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'
    - name: Run step only when any of the static files are changed, modified, or added.
     if: (condtion--??)
     run: |
       zappa manage dev collectstatic --noinput
```

I am trying to deploy a Django project using zappa and aws lambda with GitHub action.

I want to check only updated or added static files, which will have merged from develop to the main branch with the run command *`zappa manage dev collectstatic --noinput`* in yaml file.

How to make a condition for a pattern matched with all static files?

Answer (score 2):

You can try and add the GitHub Action "[`tj-actions/changed-files`](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files)", which retrieve all changed files and directories relative to the target branch or the last remote commit returning a relative path from the project root.

You can see an example in "[**GitHub Action to run mypy on changed files only**](https://dev.to/po5i/github-action-to-run-mypy-on-changed-files-only-3iip)" from [Carlos Villavicencio](https://dev.to/po5i).

In your case:

```yaml
name: CI/CD

on: push

jobs:
 deploy:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.10'
    - name: Get Python changed files
      id: changed-py-files
      uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v23
      with:
        files: |
          *.py
          **/*.py
    - name: Run step only when any of the static files are changed, modified, or added.
     if: steps.changed-py-files.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
     run: |
       zappa manage dev collectstatic --noinput
```

Replace the patterns `*.py` and `**/*.py` by the actual static file pattern you want to monitor.